# Application Stopped on Button Click

Tags: android

**Problem :**

I encountered the following error on Logcat when I clicked on a button.

I don't know what the problem is, 
and also where the problem comes from.

```
08-24 15:17:00.209 3202-3202/com.example.a.amberliu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.a.amberliu, PID: 3202
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.a.amberliu/java.util.List}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1950)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1622)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4564)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4522)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4883)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4851)
        at com.example.a.amberliu.MainActivity.onButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:23)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: please share code

Comment: main error is come from xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Declare the other Activity class:

Add this to your manifest:

```
<activity
 android:name="com.example.stockquote.StockInfoActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you register all Activities in AndroidManifest.xml?

Register activities like below snippet code of AndroidManifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:name="util.ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.example.a.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.a.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.a.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Register activity that you have to set on click like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent );
```

Hope this may help you.